# Twitter Modal box not displaying when <div> containing modal is loaded from infinite scroll

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, infinite-scroll

I have infinite scroll setup so that when the browser hits this code:

```
     <nav id='page-nav'>
            <a href='http://localhost:8888/plum/_pages/feeds_gen/feed2.php'></a>
    </nav>
```

it will load each successive feed2.php then feed3.php then feed4.php etc. until there are no more feed?.php files in the given directory. here is the infinte scroll javascript:

```
$container.infinitescroll({
          navSelector  : '#page-nav',    
          nextSelector : '#page-nav a', 
          itemSelector : '.item',
          animate      : false,
          loading: {
              msgText: '<i class="icon-th loadingicon"><p style="font-size:12px; font-family: Georgia,"Times New Roman",Times,serif;">loading...</p> </i>',
              finishedMsg: '<i class="icon-ok loadingicon"><p style="font-size:12px; font-family: Georgia,"Times New Roman",Times,serif;">loaded</p></i>',
              img: 'images/blank.png'
            }
          },
```

Finally here is the html of the modal :

```
    <div class='yo'> 
        <div id='article6e96d894690f0b8189684405c57840c0' class='modal hide fade in bigModal' style='display: none;'>  
            <div class='modal-header'>  
                <a class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>×</a>  
                <h3>New Tax Code Most Progressive Since 1979. </h3>  
            </div>  
    <div class='modal-body'>   
        <p> 6 Jan 2013 | 9:00 pm CET</p>    
        Tax Code May Be the Most Progressive Since 1979<div readability="80"><p>Republicans resisted increasing tax rates and aimed for lower revenue targets, arguing that spending was the budget's prvere income-tax burden for people at a low level of income. It was actually kind of appalling," said Alan D. Viard, a tax expert at the American Enterprise Institute, a right-of-center research group in Washington. "Policy makers in both parties realized that was bad policy and started whittling away at it" by expanding credits and tinkering with tax rates.</p><p>After those changes and the new law, comparing average tax rates for poor households and wealthy households, 2013 might be the most progressive tax code since 1979. But economists cautioned that measuring progressivity is tricky. "It's not like there is some scientific measure of progressivity all economists agreed upon," said Leonard E. Burman, a professor of public affairs at Syracuse University. "People look at different numerical measures and they've changed in different ways at different income levels."</p><p>Mr. Viard said that over time the code had become markedly rich, even if I'm getting taxed much more than a low-income person" would be, Mr. Williams of the Tax Policy Center added.</p></div><a href='http://t.co/m6inGvk6' class='btn btn-success'>Source</a>  
    <a href='#' class='btn' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</a>

    </div>  

</div> <!--END YO -->
```

And here is the HTML that launches the modal box:

```
 <a data-toggle='modal' id='article_button2' href='#article6e96d894690f0b8189684405c57840c0' >New Tax Code Most Progressive Since 1979.</a>
```

So, essentially when you click the `<a data-toggle='modal' id='article_button2' href='#article6e96d894690f0b8189684405c57840c0' >New Tax Code Most Progressive Since 1979.</a>`

Then the modal should pop up.
The problem I am having is that ANY page that is loaded by the `<nav>` the modal does not load, but the problem is that the HTML is properly in order on all of the feed2.php feed3.php etc.

Are there any alternate ways to make the modal appear when the infinite scroll loads feed2.php ?

Thanks everyone in advance for your patience and help!

Answer (score 0):

hei, you can try it

```
 <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(".post").infinitescroll({

    loading: {
        img: "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/loading.gif",
    },
    "nextSelector":"#nav-below .nav-previous a",
    "navSelector":"#nav-below",
    "itemSelector":".post",
    "contentSelector":"#content"
}, function(newElements){ 
  //callback
$('[data-toggle="modal"]').on('click', function(event){
event.preventDefault()
    // update modal header with contents of button that invoked the modal
    $('#myModalLabel').html( $(this).html() );
    //fixes a bootstrap bug that prevents a modal from being reused
    $('#utility_body').html('<div class="loading"></div>').load(
        $(this).attr('href'),
        function(response, status, xhr) {
            if (status === 'error') {
                //console.log('got here');
                $('#utility_body').html('<p>Sorry, but there was an error:' + xhr.status + ' ' + xhr.statusText+ '</p>');
            }
            return this;
        }

    );
});
}
);
});
</script>
```

I'm enter the load code to callback function on infinite scroll.. Hope my answer is not expired for you :)

Answer (score 0):

The other answer by, I Wayan Widyana is a good answer and lead me in the direction of fixing my problem, which was more or less the same as described.

Basically the Bootstrap modal's javascript setup code needs reinitialized after the jQuery load event in Infinite Scroll. This is done by rerunning the initial modal setup code using Infinite Scrolls's optional callback, which (obviously) is fired when new content is successfully loaded.

A tiny bit more information about this can be found here:

http://www.infinite-scroll.com/infinite-scroll-jquery-plugin/